# Implementing Peterson-Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm learning about Mutual Exclusion. I'm trying to implement Peterson's Algorithm in Java **without** using any of Java's synchronized features. (So, no volatile / synchronized / etc). So, I figured that I would use Peterson's algorithm because I must use some type of lockstep synchronization.

There are two thread classes, [Consumer](https://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/cis5100/examples/ch23/fig23_06_10/Producer.java) and [Producer](http://csit.selu.edu/~tkammerd/spring07/cmps431/files/PC%20Examples%20for%20Fig%205.1%20thru%205.5/Producer.java) that need to alternate modifying data. I'm linking to the code so I don't dump it all in here (I didn't write it).

I'm using a small interface
public interface Buffer

```
{
   public void set( int value );  // place value into Buffer
   public int get();              // return value from Buffer
}
```

Here's my code. I'm not sure what I did wrong, but it is not working as it should -- it isn't synchronizing (mutual exclusion isn't working).

```
public class SynchronizedBuffer implements Buffer {

    private int buffer = -1; // shared by Producer and Consumer
    private boolean[] claim = new boolean[2];
    private int[] turn = new int[2];

   // place value into buffer
   public void set( int value ){

       turn[0] = 1;
       claim[0]= true;
       while(claim[1] == true && turn[1] == 1);

       try{
                System.err.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + " writes " + value );
                buffer = value;
           }
       finally{
           claim[0] = false;
           turn[0] = 0;
       }
   }

   // return value from buffer
   public int get(){
       turn[1] = 1;
       claim[1]= true;
       while(claim[0] == true && turn[0] == 1);

       try{
           System.err.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + " reads " + buffer );         
       }
       finally{
           claim[1] = false;
           turn[1] = 0;
       }

       return buffer; 

   }
}
```

I've been able to solve the problem very easily with the volatile keyword... like this:

```
public class VolatileBuffer implements Buffer {
   private int buffer = -1; // shared by Producer and Consumer
   private volatile boolean flag = false;
   // place value into buffer
   public void set( int value ){
           while(flag == true);
                System.err.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + " writes " + value );
                flag=true;
                buffer = value;
   }

   // return value from buffer
   public int get(){
       while(flag == false);
          System.err.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + " reads " + buffer );
          flag=false;
          return buffer; 

   }
   }
```

Comment: So... what is the question?

Comment: @YoavGur sorry, the question is, what am I doing wrong with the SynchronizedBuffer code. It doesn't work. Maybe I'm implementing Peterson's Alg incorrectly? The VolatileBuffer code shows what I'm trying to do, but it uses 'volatile' which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @YoavGur I updated the original question to hopefully clarify this.

Comment: it's not clear here what features are considered off-limits for this exercise. you need *something* to tell the jvm to make data visible across threads, otherwise your checks can get optimized away, which may be what happened with your variable in the non-volatile example.

Comment: @NathanHughes is there a way to do it without using the 'volatile' and without using synchronized? I think these are the only two 'keywords' I can't use.

Comment: Umm, without using any of those tools you can't do _anything_ multithreaded in Java.  You can't even be sure two threads have the same value for a variable.

Comment: So the Peterson Algorithm cannot work without the variable being "volatile"

Comment: That is correct.  If thread A updates a non-volatile variable, there is no guarantee that thread B will _ever_ see the new value.  Even though your algorithm might happen to work in this JVM on that platform, there is no guarantee that it will work on every JVM on every platform.

Comment: if `volatile` and `synchronized` are the only 2 keywords you can't use, then you can use explicit locking using Locks: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html